# Forms authentication does not redirect to defaultUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I am developing a web on asp.net and I included FormsAutentication but I have a problem when I click login button the first time, the web redirect me  to http://localhost:2075/ instead of http://localhost:2075/Mensajes.aspx. The second time I complete user and password and click login button the web redirect me to http://localhost:2075/Mensajes.aspx. Any Ideas?

This is my web.config

```
    <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <sessionState timeout="90"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="MiWeb" loginUrl="Autenticacion.aspx" defaultUrl="Mensajes.aspx" timeout="90"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="Autenticacion.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

and here is my code behind

```
    protected void LoginUser_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        DAOUsuarios daouser = DAOUsuarios.Instance();
        try
        {
            Usuario usr = daouser.getByUsuario(LoginUser.UserName);
            if (usr != null)
            {
                    e.Authenticated = true;
                    Session["UsuarioLogueado"] = usr;
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.RememberMeSet);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoginUser.FailureText = "Error al iniciar Sesion " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual URL when you are redirected to the logon page?

Comment: the actual URL is http://localhost:2075/Autenticacion.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f

Comment: I believe the means the Return URL is specified (as /) . That's why you aren't seeing the defaultURL get used. When first navigating to the site, try leaving off the ending slash (navigate to http://localhost:2075).

Comment: No , it does not work

Comment: I have just realized that the onLoad event is being executing twice. I tried to set the AutoEventWireup in false but it does not solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case that someone need it , I found the solution of this issue. First of all the ReturnUrl=%2f is automatic of asp.net. 
If the page that you required need authentication the web site redirect you to the login page, else It redirect you to the page that you want to go in the first time. 
As my defaultDocument was set to "Autenticacion.aspx" the web site redirected me to that page. So I change the defaultDocument to "Mensajes.aspx" and it works fine.